# cant view website by domain name within my network

Tags: apache, web-services, router

I have a WAMP Server set up on my desktop. I have the desktop port forwarded on port 80 (standard Apache port). 
If I'm off my local network (coffee shop, 4G cellular, etc.), I can access my website by my domain address [Michaeland.co](http://michaeland.co).
If I'm on my local network, it 'refuses to connect' and i can only view the page by using the computers local IP.

Comment: Whatever the reason is (dynamic IP address) it clearly makes more sense to use an internal name resolution pointing to your internal address, so that the traffic does not have to leave your network only to be turned around and be sent in again.

Comment: Not quite sure if I'm grasping what you mean. How would this be done?

Comment: Easiest is to place that domain name in your `hosts` file resolving to the internal network address.

Answer (score 0):

Check with other device on your local network if it loads up your website.

If yes, ping to your domain on local network from your desktop and see the IP your request is going on.

If it's going on your desktop's IP or `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, you need to check your hosts file if there's an entry for your domain name forwarding request to `127.0.0.1`. If there's one as `michaeland.co    127.0.0.1`, remove it.

Also check if you are using proxy on your browser to access internet

Start → Control Panel → Network and Internet → Internet Options → Connections → LAN Settings

Check the box next to Use automatic configuration script and Save

Then try again if it works.

If above didn't work for you try this:

Open CMD as administrator and run the following commands one by one

```
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh int reset resetlog.txt
netsh int ip reset
netsh winsock reset
```

And now restart your pc and check again.

Comment: I have check with many devices connected to my local network and it always shows a 'refused to connect' error in the browser' but I can't view it if I use my cellphone 4g.

I just pinged it and it shows "reply from 23.127.181.xx packets sent/recieved=4

Comment: Did you ping on your local network? And I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes I pinged from both my laptop and the desktop where the server resides. I just added the ip to my hosts file as commented earlier. Still no fix

Comment: So basically the requests are going to your server from your local network via ping, but browser is not showing up the website. Check if its the issue of proxy on my updated answer

Comment: Also, Can you clear your dns cache by executing this command on your cmd `ipconfig /flushdns`? and restart browser and then try loading your website?

Comment: Did all the things you've said. I've flushed dns, released and renewed. Not sure what address to put in on the lan settings use auto configuration script though

Comment: Try running this as administrator `netsh winhttp reset proxy`

Comment: Says I have direct access no proxy server